# What's the point of new String("x") in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, types, instanceof, typeof

What are the use cases for doing `new String("already a string")`?

What's the whole point of it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There's very little practical use for `String` objects as created by `new String("foo")`. The only advantage a `String` object has over a primitive string value is that as an object it can store properties:

```
var str = "foo";
str.prop = "bar";
alert(str.prop); // undefined

var str = new String("foo");
str.prop = "bar";
alert(str.prop); // "bar"
```

If you're unsure of what values can be passed to your code then I would suggest you have larger problems in your project. No native JavaScript object, major library or DOM method that returns a string will return a `String` object rather than a string value. However, if you want to be absolutely sure you have a string value rather than a `String` object, you can convert it as follows:

```
var str = new String("foo");
str = "" + str;
```

If the value you're checking could be any object, your options are as follows:

1. **Don't worry about String objects and just use typeof**. This would be my recommendation.

   `typeof str == "string"`.
2. **Use instanceof as well as typeof**. This usually works but has the disadvantage of returning a false negative for a String object created in another window.

   `typeof str == "string" || str instanceof String`
3. **Use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)**. Check for the existence of one or more String-specific methods, such as substring() or toLowerCase(). This is clearly imprecise, since it will return a false positive for an object that happens to have a method with the name you're checking, but it will be good enough in most cases.

   `typeof str == "string" || typeof str.substring == "function"`

Comment: im creating a class which takes a parameter in its constructor. but this parameter is supplied by the user. the constructor will do something if the parameter is a string and will do something else if the parameter is not a string so i was wondering is there a way i could determine if the parameter is a string (supplied by the user). i couldn't use **str = "" + str** because i can't assume that the parameter will be only either a "true" string or a string object.. it may be some other object

Comment: @Pacerier: *"this parameter is supplied by the user"* - how is it provided? Who is the user? I really wouldn't worry about this, but I'll update my answer with the options.

Comment: The first sentence says it all.

Comment: `str = "" + str;` converts **everything** to a string. If you only want to convert String objects to strings (and Number objects to numbers, etc.), but otherwise leave things alone, you can write `str = str.valueOf()`.

Comment: console.log(new String('abc')) doesn't output anything, why??

Comment: You can check if a value is a string with Object.prototype.toString.call(value) which returns [object String] in both cases of primitive and object. Unlike instanceof this works even if the object was created in a different window. But my advice would be to never used object wrappers as there is absolutely no legitimate use case for them.

Comment: try {"".valueOf.call(value);var isString = true}catch(e){isString = false} will also tell you if a value is a string without fail. Works for both primitives and objects.

Answer (score 24):

Javascript creators created wrappers for basic types like string or int just to make it similar to java. Unfortunately, if someome makes new String("x") the type of the element will be "object" and not "string".

```
var j = new String("x");
j === "x"  //false
j == "x" //true
```

Answer (score 10):

`String` objects can have properties, while string primitives can not:

```
var aStringObject=new String("I'm a String object");
var aStringPrimitive="I'm a string primitive";

aStringObject.foo="bar";
console.log(aStringObject.foo); //--> bar

aStringPrimitive.foo="bar";
console.log(aStringPrimitive.foo); //--> undefined
```

And `String` objects can be inherited from, while string primitives can not:

```
var foo=Object.create(aStringObject);
var bar=Object.create(aStringPrimitive); //--> throws a TypeError
```

`String` objects are can only be equal to themselves, not other `String` objects with the same value, while primitives with the same value are considered equal:

```
var aStringObject=new String("I'm a String object");
var anotherStringObject=new String("I'm a String object");

console.log(aStringObject==anotherStringObject); //--> false

var aStringPrimitive="I'm a string primitive";
var anotherStringPrimitive="I'm a string primitive";

console.log(aStringPrimitive==anotherStringPrimitive); //--> true
```

You could implement overloading-*like* behavior:

```
function overloadedLikeFunction(anArgument){
    if(anArgument instanceof String){
        //do something with a String object
    }
    else if(typeof anArgument=="string"){
        //do something with a string primitive
    }
}
```

Or specify argument purpose:

```
function aConstructorWithOptionalArugments(){
    this.stringObjectProperty=new String("Default stringObjectProperty value");
    this.stringPrimitiveProperty="Default stringPrimitiveProperty value";
    for(var argument==0;argument<arguments.length;argument++){
        if(arguments[argument] instanceof String)
            this.stringObjectProperty=arguments[argument];
        if(typeof arguments[argument]=="string")
            this.stringPrimitiveProperty=arguments[argument];
    }
}
```

Or track objects:

```
var defaultStringValue=new String("default value");
var stringValue=defaultStringValue;

var input=document.getElementById("textinput") //assumes there is an text <input> element with id equal to "textinput"
input.value=defaultStringValue;
input.onkeypress=function(){
    stringValue=new String(this.value);
}

function hasInputValueChanged(){
    //Returns true even if the user has entered "default value" in the <input>
    return stringValue!=defaultStringValue;
}
```

The existence of `String` objects and string primitives effectively gives you two string "types" in Javascript with different behaviors and, consequently, uses. This goes for `Boolean` and `Number` objects and their respective primitives too.

Beware, however, of passing string (or other) primitives as the value of `this` when using the function methods `bind()`, `call()` and `apply()`, as the value will be converted to a `String` object (or a `Boolean` or a `Number` object, depending on the primitive) before being used as `this`:

```
function logTypeofThis(){
    console.log(typeof this);
}

var aStringPrimitive="I'm a string primitive";
var alsoLogTypeofThis=logTypeofThis.bind(aStringPrimitive);

console.log(typeof aStringPrimitive); //--> string;
logTypeofThis.call(aStringPrimitive); //--> object;
logTypeofThis.apply(aStringPrimitive); //--> object;
alsoLogTypeofThis(); //--> object;
```

And unexpected/counter-intuitive return types:

```
var aStringObject=new String("I'm a String object");
console.log(typeof aStringObject); //--> object
aStringObject=aStringObject.toUpperCase();
console.log(typeof aStringObject); //--> string
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `instanceof` if you really want to be paranoid:

```
if(typeof x === "string" || x instanceof String)
```

The [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/instanceof) will properly handle subclasses of String too:

> `obj instanceof ConstructorFunction` works by checking if `ConstructorFunction.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `obj`.

I don't think I've ever actually used the String class in JavaScript but there's nothing wrong with being paranoid and aiming for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you work alone and can control yourself, or on a team and there is a team guideline, or can see the code you're working with, so it shouldn't be a problem. But you can always be extra safe:

```
var obj = new String("something");
typeof obj; // "object"

obj = ""+obj;
typeof obj; // "string"
```

**Update**

Haven't though much about the implications of this, although it seems to work:

```
var obj = new String("something"), obj2 = "something else";
obj.constructor === String; // true
obj2.constructor === String; // true
```

Of course, you should check if the object has a constructor (i.e. if it is an object).

So you could have:

```
isString(obj) {
   return typeof obj === "string" || typeof obj === "object" && obj.constructor === String;
}
```

Although I suggest you just use typeof and "string", a user should know to pass through a normal string literal.

I should note this method is probably susceptible to someone creating an object and setting it's constructor to be `String` (which would indeed be completely obscure), even though it isn't a string...

Comment: so what's the best way to check if a variable is string?

Comment: Just checking the `constructor` property isn't quite enough. There could strange people out there that subclass String in JavaScript.

Comment: @mu is too short, yeh you have a point, although I thought about `instanceof` it looks like the OP was just trying to differentiate between an object, a string literal and `new String('blah')`. Whatever, the idea is out there, we can nitpick all day.

Comment: I just figure that you should go half way with pedantry, if you're going to be pedantic then go all the way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(aVariable) == '[object String]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert a String object (along with anything else) to a String primitive with `toString`:

`var str = new String("foo");
typeof str; // object
typeof str.toString(); // string`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, Even after so many years this question doesn't have a precise answer.

JavaScript has got two type of data,

1. Primitives :- string (let a = 'testStr'), number, boolean, null, undefined,symbol and bigint.
2. Objects :- Everything else (Functions, Arrays, JS Objects, ....)

Its the way JS is designed for efficiency(you know JS on V8 is like rocket) that all primitives are immutable(changing a str of num creates a new variable behind the scene) and objects are  mutable.

To support primitives to used like objects JS has this feature of AutoBoxing. So when we use any method (say toString() for number) with primitives, JS automatically converts it to the corresponding Object and then executes the method and converts it back to primitive. 
Normally we should never use the constructor(with new) and use it like a primitive only(let str = 'testStr'). Using constructor object instead of primitive might cause slow execution and complications.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to check if it is string?

Just check if it is defined or null, and otherwise defensively convert it to any type you want, either the `var bar = new String(foo);` or `var bar = "" + foo;`.