# Is there a difference between String(x) and ''

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference? Will string 2 inherit different object prototypes?

```
var s1 = 1234 + '';
var s2 = String(1234);

//s1.someNewFunc();   error?
//s2.someNewFunc();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var s1 = 1234 + '';
```

Creates a string literal. This is a javascript language primitive.

```
var s2 = String(1234);
```

The String() function also returns a primitive string literal. s2 will have the same members as s1 because they are both the same type.

However

```
var s3 = new String("1234");
```

Will create an object of type String rather than a primitive string literal. This does have different members and is of type object.

Comment: damn... now i'm more confused as to which one to use!

Comment: Don't worry about it. There isn't much use for new String()  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750656/whats-the-point-of-new-stringx-in-javascript I would just use the string literal and be done.

Comment: @Dude2TheN I recommend just using literals for primitive types. When creating your own object I would use `new myObject(...)`

Answer (score 2):

Same thing!

```
var s1 = 1234 + '';
var s2 = String(1234);

typeof s1   //string
typeof s2   //string
```

Answer (score 1):

Both will behave the same way.

Also, there is a nice explanation about string primitives vs. objects here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

> Distinction between string primitives and String objects
>
> [...] String literals (denoted by double or single quotes) and strings returned from String calls in a non-constructor context (i.e., without using the new keyword) are primitive strings. JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings. [...]

Answer (score 0):

Javascript allows you to treat primitive values as though they were objects. It does so by doing an on-the-fly coercion of the primitive to an object. That's why, even though primitives have no properties, something like this is perfectly fine:

```
"abcde".substr(1,3); //bcd
true.valueOf(); //true
```