# Why this custom Google Spreadsheet function does not work?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've writen the following code to implement a custom Google Spreadsheet function; the goal is to write all possible games between teams whose names are listed in 'names' parameter:

```
function ALLGAMES( names )
{
    var nbTeams = names.length;
    var gameList = [];

    for( var t1=0; t1<nbTeams-1; t1++ ) {
        for( var t2=t1+1; t2<nbTeams; t2++ ) {
            gameList.push( [ new String(names[t1]), new String(names[t2]) ] );
            //A. gameList.push( [ t1, t2 ] );
        }
    }

    // B. return JSON.stringify(gameList)
    // C. return [[ 'a', 'b' ], ['c', 'd']]; //using the value returned by JSON.stringify
    return gameList;
}
```

When I use the function in the spreadsheet, it fills cells *with blank values* instead of the teams names.

However, the behaviour is as expected in any of the following cases:

- If I use the A. line (pushing numbers ***instead of*** strings), it displays all the numbers correctly
- If I use the B. line (returning the JSON string for the array), it displays a correct JSON string
- If I use the C. line (returning the array in full), it works as expected.

Where is the problem?

**Edit 1:**

Here is the call to ALLGAMES I make to test the function:
[image: Google Spreadsheet call to custom function ALLGAMES]

Comment: I would suggest to print (log) new String(names[t1]), new String(names[t2]) before push to debug the issue

Comment: Add the formula that you are using to call the custom function. If you are using a reference as argument, add the values of the reference.

Comment: @Eugene the log shows correct strings, which is consistent with the case where I uncomment line B. and get the JSON string of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ALLGAMES function will receive a 2-dimensional array from your selection. You should first map it into a 1-dimensional array. 
In the loop you should leave out new String(..). In javascript you almost never use this notation, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750656/whats-the-point-of-new-stringx-in-javascript)

```
function ALLGAMES( names )
{
  names = names.map(function(item) { return item[0]; }); // adjusted

  var nbTeams = names.length;
  var gameList = [];

  for( var t1=0; t1<nbTeams-1; t1++ ) {
    for( var t2=t1+1; t2<nbTeams; t2++ ) {
      gameList.push( [ names[t1], names[t2] ] ); // adjusted
    }
  }

  return gameList;
}
```

Comment: Same for me, when using a `test` function that calls `ALLGAMES`. But this still does not work when using `ALLGAMES` directly from the spreadsheet, which is what I want.

Comment: I gave my answer an update, and now it works also directly from the spreadsheet.

Comment: Arf, indeed. I assumed the `names` array was unidimensional... My bad.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Replace

```
gameList.push( [ new String(names[t1]), new String(names[t2]) ] );
```

by

```
gameList.push( [names[t1][0], names[t2][0]])
```

## Explanation

Range references passed as arguments of custom functions are parsed as 2D arrays, so something like reference[i][j] could be used instead of reference[i]. By the other hand, `new String(string)` returns an object, but custom functions should return values, otherwise Google Sheets could not display the result properly.