# How does the String constructor function in Javascript return an Object without a key?

Tags: javascript

When I do `new String("hello")` in my console I get the following result:

```
String {"hello", length: 5}
```

The first value in the String Object that was returned doesn't have a key.

Since objects are associative/hash arrays i.e. defined and created with keys and values how is the String constructor returning an object with a value without key?

Comment: Where are you seeing that output?

Comment: Which browser? That's not what i get in Chrome. I get a char array with the proper length and the String prototype.

Comment: `length: 0` ? But still: what you see in the console is not always what the objects look like in js

Comment: @Vipinkumar Singh: String is an array of characters. That is what the console outputs you if you expand the output.

Comment: @Archer I see that on chrome in console.

Comment: @Vipinkumar Singh: Yes, you edited length from 0 to 5. Now it is equal.

Comment: @VipinkumarSingh That's just Chrome displaying it.  It's not a key/value pair where one of the pairs has no key.  Don't read too much into the console output.

Comment: @Lain How does this work internally with the String constructor function?

Comment: @Vipinkumar Singh: You do not seem to comprehend the difference between a string value and a string object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750656/whats-the-point-of-new-stringx-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

You're just misinterpreting the console's visualisation of a string object and assuming it is expressing it in the form of object literal syntax. If it would, you would see:

```
 { 0: "h", 1: "e", 2: "l", 3: "l", 4: "o", length: 5, __proto__: String }
```

But thats certainly quite unreadable, so they probably changed the way of visualizing to make it easier to read.