# Difference in these 2 Strings (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to create ***string data-types variables*** with values in 2 ways.

1. As string-literal
2. Using New Keyword

But to me it seems that these both are different in representation on **console.log**.
Can someone tell me if 2nd way doesn't return string or is it someway different?

```js
var str1 = "abc";
var str2 = new String("def");
console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
```

**Expected:**

abc, def

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/String) and look at "examples" -- _However, the constructor produces an instance of the type String (an object wrapper)_

Comment: @ggorlen - Can you please explain in your own words, and create an answer. There are 4 or 5 answers, but none satisfactory to me, as below. You are a senior guy, I think you can better explain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the point of new String("x") in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750656/whats-the-point-of-new-stringx-in-javascript)

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript has two main type categories, primivites and objects.

```
typeof new String(); // "object"
typeof '';           // "string"
```

For statements of assigning primitive values to a variable like:

```
var str1 = "Hi";
```

JavaScript will internally create the variable using:

```
String("Hi")
```

Using the new keyword works differently and returns an object instead.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `new String(something)` makes a String instance object.

The results look the same via console.log() because it'll just extract the primitive string from the String instance you pass to it.

So: just plain String() returns a string primitive. new String('xyz') returns an object constructed by the String constructor.

It's rarely necessary to explicitly construct a String instance.

Answer (score 2):

You are working with two different things.
The `var str1 = "abc"` gives you a primitive.
While the `var str2 = new String("def");` gives you a string object.
These two types behave differently

Answer (score 0):

When you print an object, often the console print the object's properties.

If is a primitive the console just print the value.

The primitive is not boxed, but if you create a string with a constructor the string is boxed in the object and always have properties.

If is just a literal, it only have properties when you access to a string's property with `.` operator because boxing occurs, but after that, it still being a literal with nothing additional added, because of that when you print `"The cat is very grumpy"`, just print the value and nothing more. primitives literals are not always objects with properties, are only objects when are boxed.

Answer (score 0):

The String object lets you work with a series of characters; it wraps Javascript's string primitive data type with a number of helper methods.

As JavaScript automatically converts between string primitives and String objects, you can call any of the helper methods of the String object on a string primitive.